# Trouble with returning the result of HttpClient content to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to write what is essentially a wrapper with asp.net-core.  I have the web request coming into the MVC controller via a standard ajax request.  From this I am creating a `HttpClient` request which I am sending to another server.  I am getting the response from this server and its valid however I am not able to get the content of that response and in effect forward that to the client who made the ajax request to my mvc controller.  I have been able to do this with with the full stack .net but not with the core libraries.

This is what I had previously with the full stack which works a treat.

```
protected HttpResponseMessage GetResponseMessage(string uriString, IEnumerable<string> responseHeaderWhiteList)
{
    var requestToRemoteService = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
    requestToRemoteService.Method = "GET";

    var responseFromRemoteService = (HttpWebResponse) requestToRemoteService.GetResponse();

    var responseToClient = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var buffer = new byte[8192];
    var responseBodyFromRemoteService = responseFromRemoteService.GetResponseStream();
    responseToClient.Content = new StreamContent(responseBodyFromRemoteService, buffer.Length);
    responseToClient.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(responseFromRemoteService.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType]);

    foreach (var header in responseHeaderWhiteList)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFromRemoteService.Headers[header]))
        {
            responseToClient.Headers.Add(header, responseFromRemoteService.Headers[header]);
        }
    }

    return responseToClient;
}
```

This is what I have in .net-core

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(string uriString, IEnumerable<string> headerWhiteList)
{
    var clientResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://remoteserver:24000/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        var serverResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uriString);

        if (serverResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var serverResponseStream = await serverResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(serverResponseStream);

            clientResponse.Content = streamContent;
            clientResponse.StatusCode = serverResponse.StatusCode;

            var serverResponseContentType = serverResponse.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First();
            clientResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(serverResponseContentType);

            foreach (var item in headerWhiteList)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> serverResponseHeaderValue;
                prizmResponse.Headers.TryGetValues(item, out serverResponseHeaderValue);

                if (serverResponseHeaderValue.Count() >= 0) {
                    var headerValuue = serverResponseHeaderValue.First();
                    clientResponse.Headers.Add(item, headerValuue);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return clientResponse;
}
```

I think my problem boils down to not understanding `HttpClient` vs `WebRequest`.  I am sure this is a simple fix although I have spent hours trying to work it out.

The response I am getting from .net-core is the following for these requests.

```
{
    "Content": null,
    "Headers": [],
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": true,
    "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
    "RequestMessage": null,
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Build": - 1,
        "Revision": - 1,
        "MajorRevision": - 1,
        "MinorRevision": - 1
    }
}
```

If I use the `ReadAsStringAsync()` from the `HttpClient` response then I can see the response and it is correct however I am not always able to guarantee the response will be in a  string format hence I want to use the `ReadAsStreamAsync()`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1507

Comment: Thanks @Tseng how did you find that so quickly?  I will try and move over to the IActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage.  Many thanks Matt

Comment: 3 seconds of search google :P Check out this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L279-L282 Content method should be one you look for, at least for strings. You can specify it's mime  type too. FileContentType for binary

Comment: It appears I need to improve my google search words